# the if statement do not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to have a try with the `clearInterval()` method in some conditions.
But it seems do not work anyway.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    list.style.position = "relative";

    list.style.left = 0;

    var move = function(){
        list.style.left = parseInt(list.style.left) + 200 + "px";  
        demo[0].innerHTML = parseInt(list.style.left);
    } 

    var myVar = setInterval(move,1000);

    if (parseInt(list.style.left) == 600) {
        clearInterval(myVar); 
    }
}
```

I don't konw why there is nothing happened when the value of left property is "600".
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Move the check inside the intervalled function.

Comment: Make sure that list.style.left is not returning "600px" instead of 600. Just to be sure you can do `parseInt(list.style.left)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it's written now, `move` hasn't been called yet, so this code has nothing to check:

```
if (parseInt(list.style.left) == 600) {
    clearInterval(myVar); 
}
```

Instead, add that condition inside of `move()` and have it end its own execution:

```
var myVar; // change scope to outside of the below function.
window.onload = function(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    list.style.position = "relative";

    list.style.left = 0;

    var move = function(){
        list.style.left = parseInt(list.style.left) + 200 + "px";  
        demo[0].innerHTML = parseInt(list.style.left);

        if (parseInt(list.style.left) == 600) {
            clearInterval(myVar); 
        }
    } 
    myVar = setInterval(move,1000);
}
```

also probably want to make the scope more global (or at least make it more evident it can be modified outside of the below function). It will be hoisted anyways, but making it more clear will help maintenance later on.

Comment: Why to move `myVar` to the global scope? It would be accessible if it was declared in onload handler as well.

Comment: @Teemu: You don't technically, but at the very least `var myVar` should be moved ahead of the definition of `move` to make it more legible. As it stands, if I stopped at `var move = function(){}` and saw it clear `myVar` i'd look upward for a definition, not downward.

Comment: Umh, Sorry, I tumbled with my comment, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is only called once in the `onload` event. After that, it never gets called again, so it never has a chance to clear the interval. If you changed your `move` function to something like this:

```
var move = function(){
    list.style.left = parseInt(list.style.left) + 200 + "px";  
    demo[0].innerHTML = parseInt(list.style.left);

    // Check to see if we should clear our interval
    if (parseInt(list.style.left) == 600) {
        clearInterval(myVar); 
    }
}
```

That'll do the check every time `move` is called. If the conditional inside the if statement evals to true, it'll clear your interval.

Comment: Like I mentioned it in my post, `list.style.left` returns a string which could be followed whith a unit (px, pt ....). It could even be a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.style.position = "relative";
    list.style.left = 0;

    var move = function(){
        if (parseInt(list.style.left) == 600) {
            clearInterval(myVar); 
        }
        list.style.left = parseInt(list.style.left) + 200 + "px";  
        demo[0].innerHTML = parseInt(list.style.left);
    } 

    var myVar = setInterval(move,1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I have a test with the code.That's right.But the value of the left in the condition can be 400 instead of 600 to make the result the same.

Answer (score 0):

`list.style.left` returns a string which could be followed whith a unit (px, pt ....). It could even be a percentage.